# iOS UITableViewCell with UIImageView display image outside the view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiimageview, uikit, sdwebimage

I have a `UITableViewCell` which an `UIImageView` in it, the image placeholder works very fine but when use `SDWebImage` to get image from url with an actual data, the image will display outside the `UIImageView`.

I have tried using below but none worked.

```
cell.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds = false
cell.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

I have attached reference image to further understanding.

[image]

UITableViewCell

[image]

I have also tried resizing the image from server to 40 x 40, but still same issue.

```
//cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(Constants.string.WEB)/assets/\(dict.image)"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: Constants.string.IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER_60))
                
cell.imageView?.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "\(Constants.string.WEB)/assets/\(dict.image)")) { (image, error, cache, urls) in
   if error != nil {
      cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: Constants.string.IMAGE_PLACEHOLDER_60)!.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
   } else {
     cell.imageView?.image = image!.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of the `imageView`? Did you set any constraints? Also set `cell.imageView?.clipsToBounds` to true. Ensure that the imageView has height and width constraint set and also leading and top constraints set.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: imageView size is 40, constraints height and width was added and I also set imageView clipsToBounds to true. I also tried resizing image to 40